# Convert string name of JS Object to instance of JS Object

Tags: javascript

I have a function, which receives 2 params: a variable, and a string representation of a data type ('String', 'Object' etc):

```
function typeChecker(variable, dataType) {
    // checks type, returns true or false
}
```

I want to convert the second parameter to a constructor, so that this expression does not throw an error:

```
variable instanceof 'Date'
```

**Question:** Is it possible to convert any of these:

```
'String'
'Date'
'Object'
```

To these:

```
String
Date
Object
```

Comment: You could use eval if it's not dangerous input

Comment: Does the dataType have to be a string, because parameters can be constructors, so `typeChecker({}, Object)` is possible

Comment: @SampsonCrowley If it is, how to figure it out in order to throw an error?

Comment: @Eduard you'd have to only accept params from a whitelist. Using bracket notation on `window` or `global` is a better option

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel I was thinking about that, but have not dared to implement this way, trying to be cautious in order not to end up in some unexpected behavior. Besides, for primitive data types I use `typeof`since was not sure about performance implications of using instanceof when not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those constructors all happen to be members of the global object (either `window` in the browser or `global` in Node.js), so you could do one of

```
variable instanceof window['Date']
variable instanceof global['Date']
```

If your constructor does not exist as a member o the global object, you can check if any prototype in the value's prototype chain is associated with a `constructor` whose `name` matches the desired string:

```
function checkIfValueIsOfTypeName(value, typeName) {
    while(value = Object.getPrototypeOf(value)) {
        if(value.constructor && value.constructor.name === typeName) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is more or less how `instanceOf` operates internally, except `instanceOf` directly compares `constructor` to the right-hand value, instead of comparing its name to a string, which is what you want to do.

Comment: I assume it is safe to use window object in this case?

Comment: @Eduard Yes, the `window` object is safe to use both in terms of availability (it is globally available) and security (unlike `eval` which could cause arbitrary code execution that you didn't intend).

Answer (score 0):

You can use typeof

```
console.log(typeof 10);
// output: "number"

console.log(typeof 'name');
// output: "string"

console.log(typeof false);
// output: "boolean"
```

Comment: Not for composite data types. This is why `ìnstanceof` is used in the question.